# how to prevent linux to kill my process and generate core file instead

Tags: linux, core-file

I am testing an application, when the application consumes most of available memory, the kernel kills my process. But I want the process dies and the core file generated, for the investigation propose. I am using redhat 5.4

Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: I already set ulimit -c unlimited

Answer (score 1):

From your "most of available memory" description, I assume that your system runs out of memory and the kernel out of memory handler kills your process. It kills by SIGTERM, so you won't get a core dump under normal circumstances.

You might be able to get a core dump by handling SIGTERM in your program and sending your process a SIGSEGV in the signal handler, thereby triggering a core dump. OTOH, in an out-of-memory situation, this might cause the death of a number of additional processes that are also killed by the OOM handler.

Answer (score 0):

The default action for many signals is a core dump.  If the program does not override Linux default signal handlers, you can cause a core dump with SIGQUIT if the proper `ulimit` is set.

SIGQUIT can be sent with `kill -SIGQUIT (process_id)` or, if the program is associated with the keyboard, by typing Ctrl-\

Answer (score 0):

you should find which signal your program will receive when OOM happened.
Then use signal function to set the handler